# Knockout subscribe to observable in js object within an observable array

Tags: knockout.js, coffeescript

I have a CoffeeScript class WorkOrderLabor (http://arcturo.github.io/library/coffeescript/03_classes.html) that has an observable `work_item_id`.

I would like to subscribe to this observable change and run some code.

This is what I am doing:

```
self.addWorkOrderLabor = ->
  wol = new WorkOrderLabor()

  wol.work_item_id.subscribe = (val) ->
    console.log val

  self.work_order.work_order_labors.push(wol)
```

This doesn't work. It actually spits out the `val` when the function is called but not when work_item_id changes.

`work_order_labors` is an observable array.

What's the best approach here? What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CoffeeScript syntax in wrong because `subscribe` is a function on the `ko.observable` where you need to pass in a callback function as the argument.

So the correct syntax is:

```
wol.work_item_id.subscribe (val) ->
    console.log val
```

So no need for the `=` which by the way overrides the orginal `subscribe` with a new function.